# Cross-domain IFrame DOM properties access from parent's JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

There are already a few similar questions but they tend to cover child-to-parent relationship.

I, on the other hand, would like to be able to get some properties of the IFrame's DOM. I don't want to manipulate anything. I only want to be able to read properties or DOM nodes. Things like attributes or contents.

AFAIK this is not possible unless I use something like `window.postMessage`. As reasonable as this solution it's based on event listeners. This requires a listener to be defined inside the IFrame and this means changing the IFrame's code. I want to avoid that.

If you want to make a cross-domain Ajax call, you can (if you have access too) set target server's headers to allow that:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

This interestingly enough doesn't work for communication with an IFrame. So my question stands:

**(How) can I access cross-domain IFrame's DOM properties?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant even tell you how many times I've ran into problems like this.

Read this [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) on circumventing the same-origin policy to find a solution that works for you. Its one of the best same-origin resources I've found on the internet.

Alex Sexton of [yayQuery](http://yayquery.com/) also put together a [screencast](http://alexsexton.com/?p=168) on some different methods

Answer (score 1):

i would give a shot to http://easyxdm.net/wp/
used it many times, quite easy to use and works in older browsers too