# Accessing an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe with a widget inside of it. The source is from a different domain. There is a form on its contents with a submission button. When it is clicked, the page that opens up is within the iframe. My question, which I have researched and haven't found an answer, is this - "Is there any way that I can access that button so that the new page opens in a separate window?"

Thank you for any help you can offer. Stackoverflow Rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not access an iframes content from another domain directly.

if you have control over the content from the other domain you can setup a messaging system.

additional information can be found here: [Cross-domain IFrame DOM properties access from parent's JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666078/cross-domain-iframe-dom-properties-access-from-parents-javascript)

Comment: So they would have to make this happen on their end?

Comment: if it makes sense to them. what is your situation and the widget specifically?

Comment: The site is a rental car site. The widget is "Reserve a Car Online" that when you hit submit, they take you to the list of cars available that fit your criteria. Its on their domain. I've seen the widget on another site and it opens it in a separate window and not in the iframe.

Comment: can you show me the other site. i will check what they are doing. is there help/reference to the widget?

Comment: http://www.martinrv.com/

Comment: No, i don't believe there is a help/reference to the widget.

Comment: It's taken care of. Thank you so much for your time. It works as expected now.